# Mobile .net Maui Problem with the display of the image in the frame

Tags: .net, image, xaml, maui

the image is not displayed inside the frame.

The folder where the image is located is called "img" and the file name is written correctly. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="pokeDex.MainPage">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <SearchBar Placeholder="Search Pokemons" />
            <Frame BorderColor="Orange" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True" Margin="50,10,50,0" Padding="100">
                <Image Source="img\pull-shark-default.png" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
            </Frame>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: That is not the correct way to specify an image source.  Please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image)

Answer (score 1):

As Jason has hinted, you are not placing the image `pull-shark-default.png` in the right location. You need place it to the **Resources\Images** folder of your project like below, where its build action will automatically be set to `MauiImage`.

[image]

When using the default `"dotnet_bot.png` like below, the image can be displayed correctly in the frame.

```
 <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
```